# Uploaded to app store successfully but showed not available in activity menu

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I uploaded my app to app store successfully and it showed in activity menu. It seemed it's not available at the begin time because it's not clickable.Like this:
[image]
And after a long time, it becomes not available with red sign like this:[image]

I'm sure I made correct profile because someone else used it and it's available. We uploaded it by Organizer. Please help me how to solve it. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens sometimes when there some error on itunes server. I have faced it multiple times.

Just try uploading a new version of your build 2.9.1 after approx 5 hours & you will see a processed build in that activity.

Hope this helps.